# Why UITableView.tableHeaderView property only accepts non-zero value when modifying its frame height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

Can anyone tell me why UITableView's `tableHeaderView` property only accepts non zero value?

I'm trying to modify the height value of my UITableView's `tableHeaderView` property for narrowing upper margin.

Below is the way I approached.

> **Setting the height property value of tableHeaderView in UITableView as 0 would actually remove the upper margin**

However, nothing has changed when applying the code as below.

```swift
//UIView has the tableView property for its one of sub views
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)))
```

I searched online about this and found some
explanation from [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview)
[image]
It seems like tableHeaderView property only accepts non zero value for its modification.
So I just set the value for height setting as `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` and it just worked.

```swift
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude)))
```

The point I'm curious about is that I still cannot undertstand why zero value and `leastNormalMagnitude` value make difference.
Shouldn't setting frame height value as 0 actually remove the UIView on screen?

Comment: Some things like this are a bit strange. When you set the height to 0, you expect nothing to be seen, however I believe when the internal implementation sees 0, it sees it as `default` hence using a really small value as a hack would overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview) :

> When assigning a view to this property, set the height of that view to a nonzero value.

There is no why. It is just like this.